# IE7 div position absolute incorrect

Tags: css, html

I have a problem with the code below as the div not placed in the correct place in IE 7 or lower but any other browser is working good

```
<div class="headericon" style="bottom:44px; position:absolute; right:12px; float:right;">
              <ul style="margin:auto;"><li style="display:inline; list-style:none;"> 
              <img src="http://**/images/truste.jpeg"  width="90"  height="35" border="0" 
                   title="Merchant Cash Advance | Merchant Cash Advance" alt="Merchant Cash Advance | Merchant Cash Advance" /></li>
                   <li style="display:inline; list-style:none;">
                     <img src="http://**/images/national.jpg"  width="80"  height="44" border="0" 
                   title="Merchant Cash Advance | Merchant Cash Advance" alt="Merchant Cash Advance | Merchant Cash Advance" /></li>
                   <li style="display:inline; list-style:none;">
                   <img src="http://**/images/electronic.jpeg"  width="90"  height="44" border="0" 
                   title="Merchant Cash Advance | Merchant Cash Advance" alt="Merchant Cash Advance | Merchant Cash Advance" /></li>

                   </ul></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `position` and `float`.

```
<div class="headericon" style="bottom:44px; position:absolute; 
     right:12px; float:right;">
```

IE7 is probably choking on this.